# How EditThisCookie can edit value of Local HttpOnly Cookie from Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, httponly, cookie-httponly

*I need to edit locally stored HtppOnly cookies* because my java program doesn't have browser capability so that I intent it to browser to view and manage same functions. But now the remote server has been updated and they use HttpOnly cookies (for security reasons) which canNOT be read by `document.cookie` function or any other `js` code. So that I wanna try to write chrome extension but before this I need to understand background process of [EditThisCookie](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/editthiscookie/fngmhnnpilhplaeedifhccceomclgfbg) because I can edit value of cookie via this extension.

So now my question is start here. I look for source code from github but after tracking `extensions apply click functions` to find its background process but it uses jquery call (I really dont understand all codes what does and how does it run so I need your help) and it does something and I want to know what is that. After that I can write my own code. Thanks.

Comment: Extensions can use [chrome.cookies](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/cookies) API.